# Android, MediaPlayer crashes after random amount of times

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have this simple bit of code which is executed everytime the NEXT button is being clicked:

```
   mediaPlayer.Stop();
   mediaPlayer.Release();
   mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(this, uri);

   btn_StartOrPause.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.btn_pause);
```

So the current song is now stopped and a new song with a new uri is being created. This works around 2 times in a row until the create line crashes saying only:

Java.Lang.IllegalStateException:

No content.

Am I using the player wrong? Why is it crashing sometimes after one successful click, sometimes straght away? The uri is always correct.

Comment: Googling this exact text for the IllegalStateException turns up nothing... are you sure that's exactly what it says?

Comment: I am absolutly 100 % percent positive

Comment: The reason I asked is that I was searching for the place in the `MediaPlayer` source ([here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/jni/android_media_MediaPlayer.cpp) and [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java)) where this occurs. I simply can't find it. Could you set a breakpoint on the exception, and go back in the stack trace, so you can tell us which part of `MediaPlayer` is throwing?

Comment: With stop points, I managed to find out that it crashes when it comes to MediaPlayer.Create()

Comment: Or, better yet, get us the full stacktrace. Use the logcat output, or `Exception.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: Somehow I managed to solve it, check my own answer and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

May you can use

```
mediaPlayer.stop()
mediaPlayer.reset()
```

and then use

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filePath);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
```

Maybe release() can make the state of MediaPlayer Error.

Comment: I tried, but it didnt change anything. Also prepare crashes immediatley.

Comment: Can you  take your Exception log here?

Answer (score 0):

After trying this out a gazillion times, it seems that THIS is the right syntax for ending one song and then recreating the other:

```
            mediaPlayer.Stop();
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(this, uri);
```

Note that my mediaPlayer is a static variable!

Thanks all!